# Cloudfront multiple origins: S3 and Load Balancer

Tags: reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudfront distribution with three origins. The first origin is a s3 bucket (Angular App) with "*" as path pattern in the behaviour, the second origin is a load balancer (WordPress App) with "/test/*" as path pattern in the behaviour, and the third one is the same load balancer with "/test".  I expect to have this behaviour:

```
   mydomain.com/*  > s3 bucket 
   mydomain.com/test > load balancer
   mydomain.com/test/* > load balancer/*
```

I think Cloudfront has a bug because, I get this behaviour:

```
   mydomain.com/test > load balancer/test (which does not exist)
   mydomain.com/test/* > load balancer/test/* (which does not exists)
```

Why Cloudfront add my path pattern to my origin path?

Comment: `example.com/test` does not match the pattern `example.com/test/*`, because it lacks a trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I had to add another behaviour -- one for example.com/test and one for example.com/test/* but now the redirection does not work properly. I have updated the questions.

Comment: Leave the Origin Path blank in origin configuration.  It's not what you assume it is.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes! It helps me a lot! Thanks.